# Is there any way (or any iOS or Android app) which i can use to change the current location of my mobile device to be detected as a US location?

Tags: applications, geolocation, ios

I want to test a mobile application which has map search and directions functionality, i.e driving directions from the current location.  Is there any way in which i can change the current location of my device to be detected as a US location?

Comment: @shivan Its not about Android only, I need to test on both Android and iOS hence I've posted it here and tagged both. Please provide solution to the problem instead of marking it down. Thanks!

Comment: Developer Settings > Allow Mock Locations! I'm not sure how it works on iOS, I'll try and find out.

Answer (score 2):

**Enable mocklocations from settings and use any application 
Eg. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=en**

Answer (score 0):

In settings we can allow mock/proxy locations in android.